# code review and pull request workflow in github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am confused with whole process of code review and pull request workflow in github.

I created a branch from master called **error_2726_fixes**. I committed all my changes and pushed **error_2726_fixes** branch to github. Now my question is how code review is done. With my research and study this is what i understand

- Create new branch (say **code_review**) from master branch and create pull request to merge branch **error_2726_fixes** to **code_review** branch.
- after incorporating all review merge **error_2726_fixes** to **code_review**
- Finally merge **code_review** branch back to master

Is this correct workflow ? Do I have to create **code_review** branch.

Could someone please explain me this process.

Comment: It's usually goes that you would do a pull request of error_2726... Into master. Then code is reviewed, if more changes are needed you push commits to error_2726...

Comment: That means no need to create code_review branch.

Comment: Yeah code review is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those highly-opinionated parts of software engineering, where there are many different ways to do it, and each way has its pros and cons. But for the sake of your question, let's consider what I would say the norm is from my time on GitHub:

1. (Optionally) You fork the repository to your own account
2. You start work on some branch, *error_2726_fixes*
3. You finish work on the branch
4. You open a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) on this branch
5. Maintainers and collaborators opt in to review your changes on the PR
6. Eventually, the branch is merged into the base branch (typically master) via this PR

Because code review is done on the *pull request* and not a *branch via commits* like you expected, there is no need for the *code_review* branch in your question.